# How to populate and select data in comboboxcell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource, datagridviewcomboboxcell

Friends, I've a datagridview in my windows application. It has 6 columns, out of which the 2nd(colindex 1) is of type combobox. Others are of textbox type. I've to populate this combobox from table1. There are two columns in table1 - ID and Name. Only Name will be displayed in the combobox. User can select any one from that combobox and write something in other 5 columns. Upon pressing save button, the ID of the selectedItem from combobox and other 5 textboxes' value will be stored in table2. When again the form will be loaded it'll fetch data from table2 and display corresponding data in datagridview. I've used datasource to populate the combobox. But it's not working. Do any one of you have any idea, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you post the source code?

Comment: **Not working** doesn't help, can you show some code ?

Comment: I've bound the column in design time.How will I get code?

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting the `DisplayMember` of the combobox to `"Name"` and the `ValueMember` of the combobox to `ID`.

And Also the bindings (For that matter any changes) you perform at design time is in `InitializeComponent` method of your class, depending on the version of Visual Studio you're using, It'll reside in a same or separate file.